# Asp.net core Model binding not displaying value after Post Request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new with asp.net core mvc. What I'm trying to do is to bind my viewmodel to my view. In the Get Request it is working fine, but after the Post Request and pass it to the view, though my viewmodels have values, it still display nothing.

This is what I have done.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Tito()
    { 

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Tito(AttendanceViewModel model, string submit)
    {      
        model.AccountModelId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("myaccountid");
        model.IsTimeIn = submit == "timein" ? true : false;
        model.DateFrom = DateTime.Now;
        Tuple<bool,DateTime> result = this.service.LogAttendance(model);

        if (result.Item1 == true)
        {                
            return View(model);
        }            

        return View();
    }
```

In my view

```
 @model TESTCOREMVC.VIEWMODELS.Attendance.AttendanceViewModel

 <form asp-action="Tito">

                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row pt-3">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="DateFrom" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">Time - In</label>                                        
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.DateFrom" readonly type="text" id="timein" class="form-control" placeholder="You don't have a time - in yet.">
                                    @*<small class="form-control-feedback"> This is inline help </small>*@
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <button name="submit" value="timein" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btntimein"> <i class="mdi mdi-login-variant"></i> Time - In</button>                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="DateTo" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">Time - Out</label>
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.DateTo" readonly type="text" id="timeout" class="form-control" placeholder="You don't have a time - out yet.">
                                    @*<small class="form-control-feedback"> This is inline help </small>*@
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <button name="submit" value="timeout" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btntimeout"> <i class="mdi mdi-logout-variant"></i> Time - Out</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

It should display the datetime after post request, but it doesn't.

Comment: Could it be that you are not hitting the `if (result.Item1 == true)` statement and therefor not returning your viewmodel to the view?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your model's inputs have a "name" attribute. Try adding:

`name="Model.PropertyName"` to your input tag

Or try using the included helper methods such as @Html.EditorFor() https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but adding the property from the model to the name attribute solved my problem